# How to solve Picasso Error at Recycler View file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, picasso

I'm getting the error below on my Build Output when I try to run my Wallpaper app on my phone :

```
error: <anonymous com.wallpapers_8k_Sad.app.Adapter.RecyclerView1$1$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onBitmapFailed(Exception,Drawable) in Target
                Picasso.with(context).load(wallpapers.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(new Target() {
```

Below is my Recyler view file where I have added Picasso and where the  :

```
        Picasso.with(context).load(wallpapers.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                MainActivity.setWallpaperImage(bitmap);
            }
            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: This is the error: ```...is not abstract and does not override abstract method onBitmapFailed(Exception,Drawable)```. It's self explanatory I guess

Comment: The method ```onBitmapFailed``` here takes two arguments: A Throwable (an Exeption) and a Drawable. You don't seem to have implemented that.